# Scrollview keeps expanding vertically the more textviews are added into it

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, android-scrollview, android-tablelayout

So I have a tablelayout and I am using weights to split the rows vertically on the screen. I am dynamically adding textviews into the third row, but as I am doing so, the more of them I add, the more the scrollview and tablerow expands vertically (even though I constrained it using weight and constraintTop...)

Screenshots:

ui with no textview: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFfHb.jpg

ui with some textviews: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQyaE.jpg

ui with a whole bunch of textviews: https://i.stack.imgur.com/agPLi.jpg (the first two tablerows become completely covered by the third row)

My goal is to have it like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UPti.jpg

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/main">

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/table"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:shrinkColumns="*"
    android:stretchColumns="*"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/UIDcontainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".2">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/UID"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TextView" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/HOWTOcontainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".2">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/HOWTO"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Approach your phone to the terminal"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/SCROLLVIEWcontainer"
        android:layout_weight=".6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true">

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/SCROLLVIEW"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/SCROLL"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
        </ScrollView>

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the code for dynamically adding textviews:

```
val scroll = findViewById<View>(R.id.SCROLL) as LinearLayout
val tv = TextView(this)
        tv.text = "This is a textview" //my own function would go here
        tv.setPaddingRelative(0, 0, 0, 16)
        tv.gravity = 1
        scroll.addView(tv)
```

Comment: Is there a reason to circumvent inflation here?  Even if it's a simple view, it still would go through more of the necessary setup to facilitate correct functionality than constructor instantiation. Edit: looking...

Comment: So considering your goal, there are easier ways to accomplish your task.  You literally don't even need the table.

Comment: A lot of people get too concerned with a flat hierarchy before it's necessary, in this situation I'd go basic and optimize after.  A problem I had to deal with at my last job, but lets make it work then make it better.  If you DM me I can guide you to a solution, i'm not gonna do it alone, though, since there's not enough for me to want to.

Comment: Use recyclerview or go to Design view in AndroidStudio and constrain the ScrollView below the "Approach your phone to the terminal"

Comment: Not sure why you are using a TableLayout with only one column per row, you are not using any features of the TableLayout, you are just using the features of it's parent class of LinearLayout. Also you have a very nested hierarchy you would be better of flattening the structure an just use ConstraintLayout with appropriate constraint to contain 2 TextViews and 1 scrollview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The weight is the `importance` when assigning space

From the Docs

> This attribute assigns an "importance" value to a view in terms of how much space it should occupy on the screen. A larger weight value allows it to expand to fill any remaining space in the parent view.

You have give the scrollview more weight thus as you add more items it takes more space.

It look like you are actually trying to assign percentages of the screen

so something like the following should meet you needs and will perform better and be more flexible

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/main">


<TextView
   android:id="@+id/UID"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="0dp"
   android:gravity="center"
   android:text="TextView"
   app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.2"
   app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
   android:id="@+id/HOWTO"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="0dp"
   android:gravity="center"
   android:text="Approach your phone to the terminal"
   android:textStyle="bold"
   app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.2"
   app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/UID"/>

<ScrollView
   android:id="@+id/SCROLLVIEW"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="0dp"
   app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.6"
   app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/HOWTO"
   tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck">

   <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/SCROLL"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="vertical"/>
</ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Producing:-

[image: Sample]